# How to import an array definition?

Tags: python, json

As a python beginner, I have a shell of a program here that converts pipe delimited text to json.  However, eventually I'll process several different pipe delimited files with varying numbers of fields the same way.

I'm looking for a way to keep the actual array specification in a separate file for the sake of modularity. So, in the code below, I'd like to be able to somehow import or otherwise read the field specifications (starting with "record_type and ending with "job_class_desc") from a separate file.

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
import json
data={}
with open('json.out', 'w') as outfile,open("./file.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
       sp=line.split('|')
       data.setdefault("data",[]).append({

        "record_type":sp[1],
        "record_sub_type":sp[2],
        "perid":sp[3],
        "group_name":sp[4],
        "job_code":sp[5],
        "accounting_code":sp[6],
        "change_record_status":sp[7],
        "change_record_status_reason":sp[8],
        "change_field_mod_indicator":sp[9],
        "begin_date":sp[10],
        "end_date":sp[11],
        "sequence_of_position":sp[12],
        "hr_subgroup_code":sp[13],
        "hr_subgroup_description":sp[14],
        "accounting_subgroup_code":sp[15],
        "reporting_unit_code":sp[16],
        "fte_percent":sp[17],
        "job_category_code":sp[18],
        "job_category_description":sp[19],
        "job_workers_comp_class":sp[20],
        "job_title_primary":sp[21],
        "required_credentials":sp[22],
        "required_credentials_descripti":sp[23],
        "work_area_description":sp[24],
        "reporting_unit_code_descriptio":sp[25],
        "exempt_indicator":sp[26],
        "job_class_code":sp[27],
        "job_class_desc":sp[28]

})
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Why not use a CSV file with a header line containing the field names? Then you can use `csv.DictReader` to load it.

Comment: Your use of `setdefault()` is very confusing. Why don't you just initialize `data = {'data'; []}` and then write `data['data'].append(...)`

Comment: @TomServo I think his question is about how to get the keys dynamically, not about how to organize the code.

Comment: Thanks guys. These files are generated as unlabelled/pipe delimited text, so unless I were to import them into an excel file (and add the 1st row labels) that's not an option.  This will ultimately be a cron job if all goes well, so manual intervention can't be a factor.  But Barmar is correct, it's about storing/retrieving the keys in a modular fashion.

Comment: What information would need to be in a key specification beyond it's name? What is the source of this data?

Comment: The data is a pipe delimited dump from a database that doesn't include column names.  But for reasons beyond the scope of this issue, it would be beneficial for me to keep the names/label file separate because the whims of local policy require that fields be readily accessible for renaming.  But the structure overall will remain constant.  So I'd like to edit a list of names/labels that in turn get incorporated in the resultant json.